# Realm cannot sort properly for capital letter in Xcode

Tags: xcode, sorting, realm

Realm cannot sort properly for capital letter in Xcode. I've wrote following Realm to sort by according speaker name.

```
RLMResults *speakers = [[SpeakerDB objectsWhere:condition] sortedResultsUsingProperty:property ascending:YES];
```

It's correctly sorted when all are small and capital letter. But when those mixed with both small and capital letter, sorting got wrong.

```
Choun-Ki JOO
Chul Young CHOI
CHAN Wing Kwong  << it gone wrong sorted.
CHEE Soon Phaik
Connie LAI
```

Please let me know how to solve that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm doesn't support case-insensitive sorting, currently.

See also... https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2970

If you'd like to get a result sorted when all are a small or a capital letter, you should add a property for sorting. The property stores same value as the speaker name property but it contains all small letters(or all uppercase). Like the following:

```
@interface SpeakerDB : RLMObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property NSString *acturalName;
@property NSString *lowercaseMame;

@end

@implementation SpeakerDB

+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)ignoredProperties {
    return @[@"name"];
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
    _name = name;
    self.acturalName = name;
    self.lowercaseMame = [name lowercaseString];
}

@end
```

(To override the setter, defining the `name` property as `ignoredProperty`.)

Then you can sort by `lowercaseMame`.

```
RLMResults *speakers = [[SpeakerDB objectsWhere:condition]
                        sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"lowercaseMame" ascending:YES];
```

Comment: that's same as what I did but marked as correct answer anyway.